# What are good practices to speed up index finding in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab

I have the following code which is executed thousands of times. By using the Profiler i identified the 2nd line (`new_inds=...`) as the most time consuming line in the whole code. Is there a better/faster way to  do this operation?

```
for j=1:length(cls)
    new_inds=[sti(:).time]==i & [sti(:).cluster]==cls(j);
    % more code here
    %
    %
    prob(j)=...
end
pr=prod(prob);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more code its difficult to definitely tell, but I would expect this to speed it up:

```
indexArg2 = [sti(:).cluster];
index1 = [sti(:).time]==i

for j=1:length(cls)
  new_inds=index1 & indexArg2==cls(j);
  % more code here
  %
  %
  prob(j)=...
end
pr=prod(prob);
```

What I am suggesting here is to take the parts of the indexing that are not related to `j` outside the `j` loop.

P.S. There is an argument that you should use `ii` and `jj` as counters instead of `i` and `j` (as they represent complex numbers).  I have read (but never seen proved) that using `ii` and `jj` is faster than `i` and `j`...